# Как в aiogram на Python выводить в консоль что хендлер загрузился?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот, android-handler

Есть `main.py` файл, `__init__.py` и сам хендлер, допустим `test.py`.

Скажите, как вывести в консоль, что хендлер загрузился?

Comment: Что такое хендлер?

Comment: Вывод в косоль print(хендлер.is_loaded)

Comment: `test.is_loaded` не работает

Comment: Покажите  хендлер код загрузки его.

Comment: И причём здесь  main.py __init__.py, test.py и aiogram?

Comment: Кода загрузки нет, в этом и проблема что я не могу это сделать.

Comment: Ответьте на первый вопрос

Comment: Если кратко то все команды/события и т.д. разбиты на файлы и называются в aiogram хендлеры

Comment: Покажите минимально воспрриводимый пример и объясните суть проблемы. Я видел что ваши вопросы закрывают, вы не задумывались почему?